# How can I merge two pandas DataFrames and deal with "removed" duplicated values properly?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have two DataFrames, where df2 is derived from df1, by removing duplicated values and then modifying some of them:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data= {'id':['A','B','C','D'], 'value':['dog','cat','bird','dog']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data= {'id':['A','B','C'], 'value':['puppy','kitty','bird']})

df1

     id   value
0    A    dog
1    B    cat
2    C    bird
3    D    dog


df2

     id   value
0    A    puppy
1    B    kitty
2    C    bird
```

I want to merge them to make the resulting DataFrame look like

```
     id   value
0    A    puppy
1    B    kitty
2    C    bird
3    D    puppy
```

Is there any straightforward way to do so?

The actual DataFrame I have is much longer and more complicated than the example I made here, where there are plenty of duplicated values that have been removed and then modified (like `dog` here). Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: why D is puppy?

Comment: You can simply merge them based on the ID and them drop the value column of DataFrame A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you can do this by making a dictionary of transformations from `df1` to values of `df2`, and then applying those transformations back to `df1`.

```
transforms = df2.merge(df1, on="id").set_index("value_y")["value_x"]
df1["new_value"] = df1["value"].map(transforms)

print(df1)
  id value new_value
0  A   dog     puppy
1  B   cat     kitty
2  C  bird      bird
3  D   dog     puppy
```

Where `transforms` is a `pd.Series` that behaves like a dictionary for us: mapping values like so:

```
print(transforms.to_dict())`
{'dog': 'puppy', 'cat': 'kitty', 'bird': 'bird'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the trick thing is how to make the dictionary. I don't know how the actual `values` are transformed from `df1` to `df2`. They are complex strings that are not as straightforward as `dog` to `puppy`. The only connection between them is they have the same `id` in the two DataFrames.

Comment: Yep! My answer addresses that for you, I merge `df1` and `df2` together by their `"id"` column and create the mappings from there (see line 1). I didn't manually create that mapping, its all programatic.

Comment: Whoop! I missed it at first sight. Yes it works! I need to do more research on the merge function I think. Appreciate a lot!